# Reversing animation movement

Tags: javascript

I'm working on building this space project and I found this really amazing code snippet that makes it look you're going in warp speed.

I'm trying to understand how it was written but I can't wrap my head around it. I want to tweak it so that the stars don't look like they're coming to you but rather move away from you. It's probably just a simple enough modification to one line but I can't seem to find it. Could anyone help with that and see how the code should look like for that tweak to happen?

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="warpspeedcanvas"></canvas>

    <script>
    Docu = document;
    documargin = Docu.body.style;
    documargin.margin = 0;
    documargin.overflow = "hidden";
    warpspeedcanvas = window, documargin = warpspeedcanvas.innerWidth, FTL = warpspeedcanvas.innerHeight, g = Docu.body.children[0], i = documargin / 2, j = FTL / 2;
    g.width = documargin;
    g.height = FTL;
    FTLk = g.getContext("2d");
    FTLk.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    FTLmath = Math, m = FTLmath.random, n = FTLmath.sin, o = FTLmath.floor, stars = 20, q = [], r = 0, warpspeed = 0.2, volume = 500, W = 1000, Q = 0.3;

    function FTLplacement(a) {
        var f = 0;
        if (a.detail) f = -a.detail / 3;
        else f = a.wheelDelta / 120;
        if (f > 0 && warpspeed < 1 || f < 0 && warpspeed + f / 25 > 0.1) warpspeed += f / 25
    }

    function FTLunits(a) {
        a.x = (m() * documargin - documargin * 0.5) * stars;
        a.y = (m() * FTL - FTL * 0.5) * stars;
        a.a = stars;
        a.b = 0;
        a.warpspeedcanvas = 0
    }
    for (var ii = 0, w; ii < volume; ii++) {
        w = {};
        FTLunits(w);
        q.push(w)
    }
    setInterval('FTLk.fillStyle="#000";FTLk.fillRect(0,0,documargin,FTL);for(a=i-documargin/2+documargin/2,f=j-FTL/2+FTL/2,h=0;h<volume;h++){b=q[h],x=b.x/b.a,y=b.y/b.a,z=1/b.a*5+1,A=n(Q*h+r)*64+W,B=n(Q*h+2+r)*64+W,warpspeedcanvas=n(Q*h+4+r)*64+W;if(b.b!=0){FTLk.strokeStyle="rgb("+o(A)+","+o(B)+","+o(warpspeedcanvas)+")";FTLk.lineWidth=z;FTLk.beginPath();FTLk.moveTo(x+a,y+f);FTLk.lineTo(b.b+a,b.warpspeedcanvas+f);FTLk.stroke()}b.b=x;b.warpspeedcanvas=y;b.a-=warpspeed;if(b.a<warpspeed||b.b>documargin||b.warpspeedcanvas>FTL)FTLunits(b)}r+=0.1;', 25);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The setInterval line contains code within a string literal, which makes it very difficult to read. I suggest you turn it into a function by replacing the first single quote with `function(){` and the closing quote with `}`
This change is possible because [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) can accept either a function or a string.
Then run it through a code formatter. You will then notice there are many assignments on an individual line, these will be easier to read if they are split onto separate lines.

Comment: Changing the warpspeed variable from 0.2 to -0.2 reverses the movement, but you then need to think about how to destroy the old stars and create new ones.